# show different colors when user posts something

Tags: php, html, database

I made a form where user posts just links and text. No images and videos. I also did some kind of validations from server side in PHP. I also did very basic SQL INSERT for storing data in database. What I want is, that whenever user posts, it is always displayed on a website with different colors from database. I Googled it but got nothing. Any idea, or help on where to start?

Simple html form:

```
<form action="checkbox1.php" method="post">
    <input name="name" id="name" type="text"/><br/>
    <input type="text" id="name2" name="name2"><br/>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" name="checkbox"><br/>
    <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: what thing you wants to show colourful ?

Comment: this may help you https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp

Comment: @TarangP The thing which is posts by user that would be just text and links. No images and videos

Comment: see @GowthamShiva comment

Comment: Thanks i understand this concept nth child selector. Its bit confusing now but i can figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.postHolder:nth-child(5n+0) .post-text {
   background: #8dc63f;
}
.postHolder:nth-child(5n+1) .post-text  {
   background: #009688;
}
.postHolder:nth-child(5n+2) .post-text  {
   background: #3f51b5;
}
.postHolder:nth-child(5n+3) .post-text  {
   background: #f44336;
}
.postHolder:nth-child(5n+4) .post-text  {
   background: #607d8b;
}
```

This example will work in your case, `.postHolder` is the class of the dive which will repeat for every post, and `.post-text` is class where you actually want to apply CSS, I have applied background color you can add whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, do you have predefined colors in the database? 
if yes! Then you will need to send color as a parameter from the database using get or post method with your post.
Then you need to use that color and apply using javascript jquery or angular whatever your frontend is.

If you have colors in your stylesheet then you need to create predefined classes with different colors; apply them to your post dynamically.

But the second option is a bit clumsy and complex, always you will need to take which was last class you applied and then apply next class.

The third option is to use nth-child but this method has some limitations like you need to write a class for every child element.

Comment: your answer opens a new door to me. I mean no i didn't defined colors for text in databse. Is there any reference page for this .? or if you show me how to do this that would be great ..

Comment: Yes! I may help in this, can you tell me which way you will prefer to get data from the database or from your local CSS.